# Print with PdfBox, render pdf in browser

Tags: java, web, render, pdfbox

I am usieng PDFBox to fill a template with some data and I wish to render it in Chrome, so that I can give the user the possibility to preview it before printing it from the web page.
Does anyone knows if PDFBox supports to render the created PDF in a browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Weird question - if you open any PDF in a properly configured browser, it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

PDFbox not directly, since it just creates the pdf. But you can simply include the pdf in your webpage through varying methods, depending on your architecture.

One simple example is:

```
<embed src="http://example.com/file.pdf" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf'>
```

More options have been discussed in this question: [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html?rq=1)